# Implementing recurring view properties

Tags: typescript, angular

Due to lack of angular 2 documentation (hence it's still in beta), I am posting this question here. I am trying to figure out how to implement a simple flag that can be set or unset on any view.

To illustrate my question see the snippet below. The "showNav" flag makes sure people will not see a navigation when logged out.

A few remarks:

- The snippet below will only work the first time since 'ngOnInit' will never be entered again. Adding a logout function would create a loophole.
- Implementing the logic within the constructor won't do us much good either as this code would have to be copy pasted on each child component, unless there's some convenient to call "super" on the parent constructor?
- I could implement a service as it seems that might be the "angular2" way of communicating between components, but this seems awfully verbose.

Any comments are welcome !

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template:  `
    <nav [ngClass]="{active: showNav}"></nav>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path:'/login', name: 'Login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'/dashboard', name: 'Dashboard', component: DashboardComponent}
])
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public showNav:boolean = false;

  constructor(
    private router:Router,
    private dataService:DataService
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!this.dataService.getStore().token) {
      this.router.navigate(['Login']);
      this.showNav = false;
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['Dashboard']);
      this.showNav = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you looking for router lifecycle callbacks  https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/CanActivate-var.html?

Comment: Why don't you subscribe to router and check if `token` is alive or not?

Comment: @EricMartinez great idea thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be after is the idea of what used to be `angular.value()` in Angular 1.

```
export var ShowNav: boolean = false;

bootstrap(MyApp, [provide(ShowNav, {useValue: ShowNav})]);
```

Then in any view this can be injected in and used just like any service or other kind of provider. The same value will be shared across all components that consume it.

```
export class MyComponent{
    constructor(showNav: ShowNav){}

    ...
}
```

Comment: Does this mean I would have to set the value of showNav in every constructor of each component that would expose the navigation (or visa versa, hide it). Of course one could set the default to be the option most commonly used. This is fine for a boolean value, but what if showNav could be any value from a short array ['apple', 'bike', 'yard', 'ship'], seems rather messy.

Comment: No, the value of ShowNav would be saved. So if in one component you set it to true, then navigate to another component, it would still be true until somewhere in your code you set it back to false.